# Why have cors error when cors is disabled in server?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, cors

I have a backend application in spring where the cors configuration is as follows:

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        return http
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfiguration()))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(configurer -> configurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/admin/**")).hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/cart/**"), mvc.pattern("/user/**"),
                                mvc.pattern("/order/**"), mvc.pattern("/orders/**"),
                                mvc.pattern("/order-product/**"), mvc.pattern("/favorite-product/**"))
                        .authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
    }
```

The backend and frontend application is run as follows in docker:

```
shoponlineback:
    image: shoponlineback:latest
    container_name: shoponlineback
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - shoponlinenetwork
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldatabase:3306/shoponline?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

      SERVER_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0
      SERVER_PORT: 8080
    depends_on:
      mysqldatabase:
        condition: service_healthy
  shoponlinefront:
    image: shoponlinefront
    container_name: shoponlinefront 
    networks:
      - shoponlinenetwork
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    environment:
      REACT_APP_SERVER_URL: http://146.59.93.226:8080
      WDS_SOCKET_PORT: 0
    depends_on:
      - "shoponlineback"
volumes:
  mysql-data:
networks:
  shoponlinenetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Host ip addres is 146.59.93.226.
Its wierd because cors allows all origins. On my local machine all works, but on docker host not .
Have you ideas how resolve it? :/

Its wierd because cors allows all origins. On my local machine all works, but on docker host not .
Have you ideas how resolve it? :/